# File Checking and Printing

Tags: c#, file-io

I am writing a program that opens up one file at a time, parses it, and outputs the parsed data into a new .txt document that is named based off of the file coming in. There are over 50 files that are going to be read and parsed.

So if the **opened** file was named something like this: `STACK-OVERFLOW-125663-D2.txt`, the **output** file would be something like this `125663-D2.txt`.

Each time a file is read, it is parsed for their part numbers. Each file will contain lines similar to this *(The 8th seperated comma values (ie, 119082, 119083, 119040, 119085, 119084) are the part number values.)*:

```
"00003",6,"D","C20",-70.10,42.06,90.00,"119082",0,1,2,0,0,"",0,"001"
"00004",6,"D","C21",-67.91,42.06,90.00,"119082",0,1,2,0,0,"",0,"001"
"00005",13,"D","C23",-66.91,59.07,180.00,"119083",0,1,2,0,0,"",0,"002"
"00006",13,"D","R10",-77.32,66.88,90.00,"119040",0,1,2,0,0,"",0,"003"
"00007",13,"D","L3",-77.64,77.48,90.00,"119085",0,1,2,0,0,"",0,"004"
"00008",20,"D","D1",-62.91,103.77,0.00,"119084",0,1,2,0,0,"",0,"005"
"00009",21,"D","D1",-25.83,103.77,0.00,"119084",0,1,2,0,0,"",0,"005"
"00010",14,"D","L3",-40.56,77.48,90.00,"119085",0,1,2,0,0,"",0,"004"
"00011",14,"D","R10",-40.24,66.88,90.00,"119040",0,1,2,0,0,"",0,"003"
```

Now what I need to do is check another .txt file.. let's say it is called "DATABASE.txt" to see if these part number exist in there already. This data base file will look something like this:

```
119082:    125663-D2, 123456-A1,
119083:    125663-D2,
119085:    125663-D2, 123456-A1, 987654321-Z11234, 1111111-B50
```

So, in the DATABASE.txt file and the file opened above, I want to check all of the part numbers from the opened file and see if they exist in the data base.

- If the part does exist, I want to concat the filename (the output file) to the end of the line that the part number was found on.
- If the part does not exist, I want to add the part to the file and sort the file using `list.Sort()`.

I am unsure on how to do this, can anyone help?

---

Here is some of my code so far:

```
List<string> partNumberLines = new List<string>();
string file = openFile.FileName;
string splitFile = file.Split('\\');
string[] savedName = splitFile[splitFile.Length - 1].Split('.');
string[] lineNumber = savedNamed[2].Split('-');
string fileName = savedNamed[1] + "-" + lineNumber[0] + ".txt";

foreach (string line in fileList)
{
    string[] splitLine = line.Split('\n');
    for (int i = 0; i < splitLine.Length; i++)
    {
        string tempSplit = splitLine[i].Split(',');  // splits each line by commas
        if (tempSplit.Length.Equals(16))
        {
            tempSplit[7] = tempSplit[7].TrimStart('"');  //trims the quotes from the part numbers
            tempSplit[7] = tempSplit[7].TrimEnd('"');
        }
    }
}
partNumberLines = partNumberLines.Distinct().ToList();  //gets rid of duplicate partnumbers in one file.
```

---

So my code is getting all of the part numbers and the name of the file.. I just do not know how to open up an existing file (and if it does not exist, create it) and search through the file and look for matches in the **List:** `partNumberLines`. And if it matches, concat the **file name**  to the current line. If it does not match, create a new line and add the part number and file name and then sort the file numerically by part number.

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: +1 for the details and how the question can be used in other circumstances.

Comment: You mention, as far as I can tell, 3 different files (input, database, and output). Can you clarify what the output file is supposed to look like if the part exists in DB.txt or not?

Comment: @tkeE2036: What I mean by the filename is the actual name of the document that will be saved. So if you look at the `DATABASE.txt` section above you will notice the *partnumber* on the left side, followed by a **":"**. The next few 'words' are the different filenames, or files, that contain that partnumber.. So basically I am having a list of part numbers and the corresponding files that contain each specified part number listed after the partnumber.. does that clarify a bit more?

Comment: @theNoobGuy: Yeah it does. Can DATABASE.txt exist before this program is ran so it would have to append to that existing file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope you haven't given up.  Here's a sample class.  I've completed it from my last post.  Save your database data above to `database.txt` and your parts data to `parts.txt` and modify the paths to see how it works.  Hope it helps you.  If you have any more questions, feel free to ask.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        private class DataBaseRecord
        {
            public string PartNumber { get; set; }
            public List<string> FileNames { get; set; }
            public DataBaseRecord(string _PartNumber, List<string> _FileNames)
            {
                PartNumber = _PartNumber;
                FileNames = _FileNames;
            }
        }

        private class DataBase
        {
            public string databaseFile { get; set; }
            List<DataBaseRecord> records;
            public DataBase(string _databaseFile)
            {
                databaseFile = _databaseFile;
                records = new List<DataBaseRecord>();
            }
            public void AddRecord(string partNumber, string fileName)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(partNumber))
                    return;

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileName))
                    return;

                bool exists = records.Count(x => x.PartNumber == partNumber) > 0;
                if (!exists)
                {
                    records.Add(new DataBaseRecord(partNumber, new List<string>() { fileName }));
                }
                else
                {
                    var record = from x in records where x.PartNumber == partNumber select x;
                    foreach (DataBaseRecord dbr in record)
                    {
                        exists = dbr.FileNames.Count(x => x == fileName) > 0;
                        if (!exists)
                            dbr.FileNames.Add(fileName);
                    }
                }
            }
            public void Read()
            {
                // read all database records into data structure
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(databaseFile))
                {
                    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        string line = sr.ReadLine();
                        string partNumber = line.Split(':')[0].Trim();
                        if (partNumber[0] == '\"')
                            partNumber = partNumber.Substring(1, partNumber.Length - 2);
                        string[] files = line.Split(new string[]{":"}, StringSplitOptions.None)[1].Split(new string[]{","}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                        List<string> fileNumbers = new List<string>();
                        foreach (String file in files)
                        {
                            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(file))
                            {
                                fileNumbers.Add(file.Trim());
                            }
                        }
                        records.Add(new DataBaseRecord(partNumber, fileNumbers));
                    }
                }
            }
            public void Write()
            {
                // write out database using the records
                var sortedRecords = from x in records orderby x.PartNumber select x;
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(databaseFile))
                {
                    foreach (DataBaseRecord record in sortedRecords)
                    {
                        string line = record.PartNumber + ": ";
                        for (int index = 0; index < record.FileNames.Count; index++)
                        {
                            line += record.FileNames[index];
                            if (index < record.FileNames.Count - 1)
                                line += ", ";
                        }
                        sw.WriteLine(line);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // replace with name of your database
            DataBase db = new DataBase(@"C:\Users\jondoe\Desktop\DataBase.txt");
            db.Read();

            // replace with list of your parts files
            string[] partsFiles = new string[] { @"C:\Users\jondoe\Desktop\parts.txt" };
            foreach (string partsFile in partsFiles)
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(partsFile))
                {
                    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        string line = sr.ReadLine();
                        string partNumber = line.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None)[7];
                        if (partNumber[0] == '\"')
                            partNumber = partNumber.Substring(1, partNumber.Length - 2);
                        db.AddRecord(partNumber, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(partsFile));
                    }
                }                
            }

            db.Write();
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**

If you want a static database and you want to allow the user to choose a parts file, then you could do this in a button click event:

```
private void btnOpenFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataBase db = new DataBase(@"C:\Users\JonDoe\Desktop\DataBase.txt");
    db.Read();

    using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog())
    {
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ofd.FileName))
            {
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string line = sr.ReadLine();
                    string partNumber = line.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None)[7];
                    if (partNumber[0] == '\"')
                        partNumber = partNumber.Substring(1, partNumber.Length - 2);
                    db.AddRecord(partNumber, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(ofd.FileName));
                }
            }
            db.Write();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a form that I am opening an original file and stripping it to the lines above *(in the question)*. After the data is stripped it is saved to a new file that changes its name on every file opened. How can I change your hardcoded `string[] partsFiles = new string[] {` @"C:\..." };` to allow for these changes. I want your code to run on the new file that is created every time a document is **opened** in the GUI form. How can I do this?

Comment: I figured that out... However, now my problem is creating new instances of the code you have above on the click of a button... Right now I click the open button, open the file, read the file, print out the file two 2 different files (database.txt and parts.txt). Once all this is done I am calling `this.Hide();` which hides the GUI. After the GUI is hidden, I want to open a new instance of the code you have above.. how do I properly do that? Unless it is easier to not `hide` the GUI and instead clear all the fields?

Answer (score 1):

Do not parse CSV yourself.  Use [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/) Library for that.  There can be a lot of exceptions, and FileHelpers handles those really well.

Secondly, you're doing enough data operations were a simple database might help.  Maybe SQL Express, or a single file embedded database ( SQL Server Compact, SQLite ).

Finally to do this manually, you simply have to build out your tables in memory.  What you really have is a *Many-to-Many* relationship between part numbers and files.  So you have two tables and a join table inbetween.

Now since "filename" has only a single attribute ( *filename* ) in your example, it can be appended in the join table as an additional column.  So you have 2 tables.  The second looks like

```
JoinTable
-------------------
PartNum | Varchar
Filename| Varchar
```

The first table you already have.

So if you replicate these two tables in memory using `List<List<string>>` you should be able to finish this with LINQ with no trouble at all.  Though personally I would build out new classes or at least structs to represent the two table tuples.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick run at it .. it could definitely use improvement but its a start :)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    public class FileIo
    {
        private Dictionary<int, CommaDelimitedStringCollection> dataBase;
        private const string DATABASE_PATH = @"D:\Temp\Test\DATABASE.txt";

        public void Run()
        {
            var files = new List<string> { @"D:\Temp\Test\Test1.txt", @"D:\Temp\Test\Test2.txt", @"D:\Temp\Test\Test3.txt" };

            dataBase = GetDatabase();

            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                Search(file, GetPartNumbers(file));  
            }

            WriteFileContents(DATABASE_PATH, BuildPartsDbStr());
        }

        private void Search(string fileName, List<int> partNums)
        {
            foreach (var partNum in partNums)
            {
                var path = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);
                if (dataBase.Keys.Contains(partNum))
                {
                    dataBase[partNum].Add(path);
                }
                else
                {
                    dataBase.Add(partNum, new CommaDelimitedStringCollection { path });
                }
            }
        }

        private string BuildPartsDbStr()
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            var db  = from x in dataBase orderby x.Key select x;

            foreach (var record in db)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", record.Key, record.Value));
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }

        private Dictionary<int, CommaDelimitedStringCollection> GetDatabase()
        {
            var contents = GetFileContents(DATABASE_PATH);
            var commaStr = new CommaDelimitedStringCollection();
            var db = new Dictionary<int, CommaDelimitedStringCollection>();
            var id = 0;
            var collection = new CommaDelimitedStringCollection();

            for (var i = 0; i < commaStr.Count; i++ )
            {
                var str = commaStr[i];
                if (str.Contains(":"))
                {
                    collection.Add(str.Split(':')[1]);
                    if (i > 0) db.Add(id, collection);
                    collection = new CommaDelimitedStringCollection();
                    id = int.Parse(str.Split(':')[0]);
                }
                else
                {
                    collection.Add(str);
                }
            }

            return db;
        }

        private List<int> GetPartNumbers(string filePath)
        {
            var contents = GetFileContents(filePath);
            var commaStr = new CommaDelimitedStringCollection();
            var result = new List<int>();                

            commaStr.AddRange(contents.Split(','));

            for(var i = 7; i < commaStr.Count; i += 15)
            {
                result.Add(int.Parse(commaStr[i].Replace("\"", string.Empty)));
            }

            return result;
        } 


        private string GetFileContents(string path)
        {
            using (var stream = new StreamReader(path))
            {
                //yes I know this is evil - I don't have all night :P
                return stream.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }

        private void WriteFileContents(string path, string contents)
        {
            using (var stream = new StreamWriter(path, false))
            {
                stream.Write(contents);
                stream.Flush();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: On further thought this would probably be better solved using a regex to strip the data out of the files and into the db/partNums list. Would probably be quicker than all the loops.